# Intellij Idea how to keep track of files from different branches

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

How do you keep track of classes/file from branches different then main branch of your project?
I mean, when working on large project, I'm sometimes updating files to other branches and leave it as it is.
How to check the list (?) of files from different branch than the one checked out initially?

I'm working with `SVN` if it makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Changes`, `Repository` panel to see commits against the whole svn repo, therefore you can keep an eye on commits as they happen. You can then merge two branches using the `VCS` merge menu which prompts you to configure branches in the `svn working copy` panel.

Comment: this is not the case I'm talking about. I'm just switching(updating) single files to different branch to see history of a file etc. and sometimes I left it as it is (inconsistent with current project branch although not causing any errors) and my question is if I can see all switched (updated) files to different branch